# Test email with regular expression via Firebase Firestore security rule

Tags: regex, firebase, validation, email, security

I am working on a contract form hosted on Firebase. User can submit a form without authorization (anonymous authorization only). I have client side data validation on form but i struggle to test email with regular expression via Firestore security rule on the server side. Here is what i have in RE2 syntax:
`allow create: if request.resource.data.email.matches("/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i");`
I have tried without "/", also does not work. Following regex works perfectly for telephone number, however:
`allow create: if request.resource.data.tel.matches("^[+][0-9]{9,}$");`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `.matches('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$')`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks a lot for the tip! It works! With small correction: `\.[A-Za-z]` is not accepted, has to be `\\.[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.email.matches('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$')
```

That is, you should pass the regex as a string literal, not as a regex literal enclosed within a string literal.

Since in this case you cannot use `/i` flag you need to add `a-z` to your pattern.

If it is a RE2 pattern, you may also use a `(?i)` case insensitive inline modifier:

```golang
'(?i)^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}$'
```